# "Project description file" error in git?

Tags: git

I've a small project that I want to share with a few others on a machine that we all have access to. I created a bare copy of the local repo with

```
git clone --bare --no-hardlinks path/to/.git/ repoToShare.git
```

I then moved repoToShare.git to the server.

I can check it out with the following:

```
git clone ssh://user@address/opt/gitroot/repoToShare.git/ test
```

I can then see everything in the local repo and make commits against that. When I try to push changes back to the remote server I get the following error.

```
*** Project description file hasn't been set
error: hooks/update exited with error code 1
error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Git installs a bunch of pre-configured hooks in the hooks directory, out of the box they do not execute. If you happen to allow execute on them (Eg. chmod +x) then git will try to run them. The particular error pops up cause the default update is failing to run. To fix, delete the default update hook.

Does [this link](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=49#c15) help? From the text:

> A colleague of mine experienced a
>   similar issue here where push was not
>   working. You could not push to a local
>   or remote public repository. He was
>   getting a project description file
>   hasn't been set error thrown by
>   .git/hooks/update. This error was not
>   happening for the same project on a
>   linux or Windows box, and seemed to be
>   happening only on Windows Vista. From
>   my research hooks/update is not by
>   default executed, but in windows vista
>   the file permissions meant that it
>   was. Deletion of hooks/update resolved
>   these issues.

Comment: The exact problem is that if the hooks/update script has execute permissions, it will try and execute, which means your stuff will break. :(

Comment: Git 1.6 should fix this problem by ignoring the pre-installed hooks until you rename them. So newer Git users on Windows should stop seeing this problem once Git 1.6 becomes widespread.

Comment: Had this occur to me using 1.6.0.4 in Cygwin. Deleting the update file fixed it for me.

Comment: I was having the same problem here. Just renamed the update file and it also worked. I am using git version 1.7.1 on the remote (pushed-to) repositoy and 1.7.4 at the local (pushed-from). But I would really like to know why it did work though.. and also what kind of effects could this change bring.

Answer (score 16):

Deleting hooks/update is not what you want to do.

Just change .git/description to whatever you want - for instance "FOOBAR repository", or, if you are French, "Le depot de FOOBAR".

Comment: I definitely have some content in .git/description, yet I still get the error.

Comment: The content must be different of the one git added by default.

Comment: I'm going to put the french description in even though I cannot speak the language...

Answer (score 2):

I got this error as well when pushing from Mac OS X (Git version 1.6.1, compiled with [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts)) to an Ubuntu remote repository (Git version 1.5.4.3)

I've added the name of repository in the `.git`/description file on both the local and remote repository and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

chmod -x hooks/update

the above command executed from your .git directory will only remove execute permissions from the update hook. No need to delete the file

Answer (score 1):

Delete file or prevent its execution seem extreme solutions. If you don't want to add a project description, it's enough comment or delete the lines in hooks/update that are blocking the push actions. In my file, these lines are:

```
# check for no description
projectdesc=$(sed -e '1q' "$GIT_DIR/description")
if [ -z "$projectdesc" -o "$projectdesc" = "Unnamed repository; edit this file to name it for gitweb." ]; then
       echo "*** Project description file hasn't been set" >&2
       exit 1
fi
```

When I commented them out, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as @dragulesq but with a [Red Hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) server.

To be a bit more verbose just put whatever you want as a string in the .git/description file on your local (in my case my Mac OS X); I put *website* and then on the remote server that hosts the Git repo (as so to speak) edit the .git/description file and put the same string in again (e.g. *website*).